# Mojolicious Angular POST JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, perl, mojolicious, mojolicious-lite

i am new to Perl and Mojo and i've got one problem by receiving POST-Data from Angular:

My AngularCode is

```
var datainput = JSON.stringify({"test":"orcl"});
$http.post('http://localhost/perltest/perltest.pl/post', datainput)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("post geschickt");
        console.log(headers());
        console.log(data);
        console.log("data back: " + JSON.stringify(data));
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
```

My Mojo-Sub looks like:

```
post '/post' => sub {
my $self = shift;

my $json = $self->req->json;
print header(-type => "text/html"); 
print Dumper($json->{test});
};
app->start;
```

The Result i get is:
$VAR1 = undef; Content-Length: 0 Status: 404 Not Found Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:49:57 GMT

What is wrong?
It seems to me that $json = $self->req->json is not getting the JSON-String from POST ?

Comment: You are not supposed to `print` in Mojo. You need to return something. Also, how are you running your app? With `morbo`?

Comment: Please [edit] the new information you posted as an answer into your question with the [edit] link. Then please delete that answer. It will be downvoted and deleted by the community if don't do it yourself.

Comment: Don't use print() you use $self->app->log->debug($self->dumper(...)). Print() is unreliable.

Comment: If you dumper `$json->{test}` you don't know if `test` existed because of autovivification. You should dumper `$json` and look if it's undef or an empty hashref or whatever. If you want to print directly, then write `print STDERR $foo;`.

Answer (score 3):

Angular passes posts in via the body of the request, so this is how I handle those.

```
post '/post' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $json = $self->req->body;
    #use Mojo::JSON qw(decode_json encode_json) at top of app
    my $perl_hash = decode_json($json)
    #Do something with the hash, like pass to a helper or model
    $self->render(json => $return_from_model_or_helper);
};
```

Jquery posts will use the params and not the body.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs for the `json` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::Message#json) say that `undef` is returned if decoding didn't work or if the request was empty. You should first look at the request body.

```
warn Dumper $self->req->body;
```

This will output the raw request body to your application console or log. If you run `morbo app.pl`, that's your console window. Look at what you see. Is the content there? Is the content-type correct?

Then take it from there.

---

You can't just `print` in the  middle of your route handler. You need to use the application object to `render` your content.

```
post '/post' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    my $json = $self->req->json;

    $self->render( text => $json->{test} );
};
```

This way, Mojolicious takes care of everything for you. There is also no need to set the content type explicitly. It's going to use something sensible automatically.

However, you're getting a 404 back. That might be because of the `print`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I think, he gets 404 because nothing is rendered.

Comment: @Helmut possible, but is that really a _not found_?

Answer (score 1):

1. The    `404 Not Found` indicates the resource is not found. Please double check if your application is available under `http://localhost/perltest/perltest.pl/post`.
2. You should not use print(), because it's not reliable (sometimes it works and sometimes not). If you want to log text into your console, please use $self->app->log->debug(). Mojolicious also has $self->dumper, you do not need to include the external module `Data::Dumper`.
3. Check the data which is actually send. You can use a service like http://requestb.in/. If you recieve correct JSON; I would strongly expect the URL is not correct (see point 1.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to JSON-stringify your object.

Try replacing your first angular line with this:

```
var datainput = {test: "orcl"};
```